# Dropdown menu not closing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a very basic menu in JQuery. My basic idea is that when I click a button, I want my menu to pop up. When that menu pops up, two things happen: 1) the menu is shown, and 2) the button is given a new class to be able to close. It's like JQuery is completely ignoring this new class. What do?

http://codepen.io/asilhavy/pen/apjvYo?editors=1010

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
 $(".drop-item").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
 $(".fa-drop").addClass("fa-angle-double-down").removeClass("fa-angle-double-right");
 $(".dropdown").addClass("close-dropdown").removeClass("dropdown");
});
$(".close-dropdown").click(function () {
 $(".drop-item").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
 $(".fa-drop").removeClass("fa-angle-double-down").addClass("fa-angle-double-right");
 $(".close-dropdown").removeClass("close-dropdown").addClass("dropdown");
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f19ebae6ca.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="popup">
 <li class="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-drop fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Click to Dropdown</li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the problem is  when you do `$(".close-dropdown").click(function () {`

there is no `.close-dropdown` in the dom to attach that event listener ,so when after some time you attach the class `close-dropdown` to div, there is no event listener to it.

this is a known problem and one solution is `event delegation`

read more about it here ... https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

i have delegated event to body tag , but you can decide for that after understanding the delegation

```js
$('body').on('click', ".dropdown", function () {
    //console.log(2)
 $(".drop-item").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
 $(".fa-drop").addClass("fa-angle-double-down").removeClass("fa-angle-double-right");
 $(".dropdown").addClass("close-dropdown").removeClass("dropdown");
})


$('body').on('click', ".close-dropdown", function () { 
  //console.log(1)
  $(".drop-item").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
 $(".fa-drop").removeClass("fa-angle-double-down").addClass("fa-angle-double-right");
 $(".close-dropdown").removeClass("close-dropdown").addClass("dropdown");
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="popup">
   <li class="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-drop fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Click to Dropdown</li>
   <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add and or delete classes. 
The Javascript code needs to be initialized when the document is ready.

If you use .addClass() or you delete the associated class it won't reinitialize without reloading the page.

Using your Code:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.drop-item').toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use 1 function to handle this instead of 2. Check my jsfiddle.

var on = false;

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
if(on) {
    $(".drop-item").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    $(".fa-drop").removeClass("fa-angle-double-down").addClass("fa-angle-double-right");
  on = !on;
} else {
    $(".drop-item").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
    $(".fa-drop").addClass("fa-angle-double-down").removeClass("fa-angle-double-right");
 on = !on;
}

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yw7ff0wz/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's event delegation syntax with `.on()` instead of using `.click()`. When you use `.click()` and add and remove the `dropdown` class, your bindings are lost.

```js
$("#popup").on("click", ".dropdown", function () {
 $(".drop-item").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
 $(".fa-drop").addClass("fa-angle-double-down").removeClass("fa-angle-double-right");
 $(".dropdown").addClass("close-dropdown").removeClass("dropdown");
});
$("#popup").on("click", ".close-dropdown", function () {
 $(".drop-item").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
 $(".fa-drop").removeClass("fa-angle-double-down").addClass("fa-angle-double-right");
 $(".close-dropdown").removeClass("close-dropdown").addClass("dropdown");
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f19ebae6ca.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="popup">
 <li class="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-drop fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Click to Dropdown</li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="drop-item hide">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```